# How do I send e-mail using .NET 4 if smtp server requires authorization?

Tags: c#, .net

How to send e-mail using .NET 4 if smtp server requires authorization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass credentials to the Smtp Server variable

```
smtpServerInstance.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password"); 
smtpServerInstance.Send(mail);
```